# How to describe someone who is more "respectful" to woman?

Tags: adjectives

I know a guy or two that seem to be more respectful and more forwarding to a woman or women in general. For instance, a response may not be clear to this person when told by a man, but when told by a woman, they seem to grasp better attention. They also care more about the safety of a woman than a man, even if a man had a worse problem than the woman is having, yet they seem to direct their attention to the woman. They also get angry to slightly-offensive jokes told by men, and yet they laugh hysterically to women.
Despite these hypocritical acts, i don't know a way to describe them, all i know is that i sense a sexual vibe from these 2 men, yet they claim not to be wanting any sexual relations with women. **So in conclusion** what would be the word / adjective to describe this gender-respectful act? And is there any alternatives towards men?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to [@MathieuK.](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/106063/mathieu-k)'s [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/400902/194281), this particular form of **sexism** is called **benevolent sexism**:

> Benevolent sexism is a form of paternalistic prejudice (treating a lower status group as a father might treat a child) directed toward women. ... Benevolent sexism, however, is an affectionate but patronizing attitude that treats women as needing men’s help, protection, and provision (i.e., as being more like children than adults).

Source: [psychology.iresearchnet.com](https://psychology.iresearchnet.com/social-psychology/prejudice/benevolent-sexism/)

This is different to the stereotypical *hostile sexism*, and may be why you were confused.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, that page defines benevolent sexism in quite a sexist way, presupposing that sexism is uniquely men’s treatment of women. The [Wikipedia article on ambivalent sexism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambivalent_sexism) does a better job of describing it neutrally (one gender towards another, instead of just men towards women), and though it too mostly focuses on the male → female side of things, it at least says so outright and gives reasons for it.

Answer (score 2):

Behaviour favouring or discriminating against one sex as compared to another is **sexism**, and parties engaging in such behaviour are being **sexist**.

Answer (score 0):

**Chivalrous** may be used

> chivalrous (of a man or his behaviour) - courteous and gallant, especially towards
>   women. ‘shall I be chivalrous and offer you my coat?’ (OED)

Comment: Which according to some sources is the same as 'benevolent sexism'. I think the OP wants a perjorative term, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The words I'd use are **[obsequious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obsequious)**

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Obedient or attentive to an excessive or servile degree. ‘they were served by obsequious waiters’

and **[insincere](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/insincere)**

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not expressing genuine feelings. ‘she flashed him an insincere smile’

In this instance, I'd simply say that they are "obsequious and insincere towards women".

I'm not aware of a single word for this.